# Delete OCR word from Image (OpenCV,Python)

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, bounding-box

So, from what I can begin..

I am working with OCR. The script works pretty well for what I need. It detects the words with an accuracy which for me is ok.

This is the result: 100% accuracy with attached image.

[image: syd]

```
from PIL import Image
import pyocr.builders
import os

os.putenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR")

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
tool = tools[0]
langs = tool.get_available_languages()
lang = langs[0] #eng

file = "test.png"

txt = tool.image_to_string(Image.open(file), lang=lang, builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder())
print(txt + '\n')

'''
word = ['SHINE','ON','YOU','CRAZY','DIAMOND','SYD']

if word[2] in txt:
    print("## WORD IN LIST ##")
else:
    print("## NOT IN LIST ##")'''
```

Now the question: how can I remove from image a word which exist in the output OCR-list (in the code named `txt`) ?
I mean, if the word SHINE exist as output in console (and in list), how can I delete it in image ? Or, if not remove, create a mask so I can hide it...

I think the ocr work by selecting areas of text and creating a bounding box around the text. In this case, how to delete (or even show) this ROI/bounding box ?
In the `pyocr` documentation there are some hints about this function (show bounding box) but I don't know how to use it.

Any help/hint is appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: this code show me the bounding box for each character

```
import csv
import cv2
from pytesseract import pytesseract as pt

pt.run_tesseract('test.png', 'output', lang=None, boxes=True, config="hocr")

# To read the coordinates
boxes = []
with open('output.box', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ' ')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 6:
            boxes.append(row)

# Draw the bounding box
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
h, w, _ = img.shape
for b in boxes:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(int(b[1]),h-int(b[2])),(int(b[3]),h-int(b[4])),(255,0,0),2)

cv2.imshow('output', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: sdsdf]

How can I tell it to show me only the first (whole) word ?

Comment: Determine which one is in word or detect which character is in sequence by check distance of it bounding box (may be `<= fixed_threshold` which you have set).

Comment: @Link i ran this code and got following error \                                             
TypeError: run_tesseract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'boxes' Process finished with exit code 1 –, how to fix it?

Comment: You can fill the box with white `cv2.rectangle(img,(int(b[1]),h-int(b[2])),(int(b[3]),h-int(b[4])),(255, 255,255),-1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold
- Dilate to connect contours
- Find contours and extract ROI for each word
- Perform OCR and remove word

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

Next we invert the image and dilate to form a single contour for each word

[image]

From here we find contours and extract the ROI for each word. Here's the detected ROIs

[image]

We throw each ROI into Pytesseract OCR. If the OCR result is a word  we want to remove, we simply "delete" the word by filling in the ROI with white and replace it in the original image

---

With

```
words_to_remove = ['on', 'you', 'crazy']
```

The result is

[image]

Similarly with

```
words_to_remove = ['on', 'you', 'shine', 'diamond']
```

The result is

[image]

Finally with

```
words_to_remove = ['on', 'you', 'crazy', 'diamond']
```

[image]

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

words_to_remove = ['on', 'you', 'crazy', 'diamond']
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
inverted_thresh = 255 - thresh
dilate = cv2.dilate(inverted_thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng',config='--psm 6').lower()
    if data in words_to_remove:
        image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```