# How to customize parameters for face detection by using face cascade

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have a simple face detection implementation as following

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
filename = "path/to/image"

img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imshow("Original image", img)

face_region = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.1, 4)

for (x, y, w, h) in face_region:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

after running the code, I got the following result

[image]

As you can see that, the implementation detects two faces! How can I get rid of this kind of false detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first delete the textual data like in this link [Delete OCR word from Image (OpenCV,Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226647/delete-ocr-word-from-image-opencv-python)

after that try to use you face detection code...then it will improve your accuracy